# How can I convert numbers to dates and then obtain the latest day?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a list of numbers like this:

```
20151114
20151115
20151116
```

And I need to obtein the latest day. If today is 2015/11/17, the latest number should be this:

```
 20151116
```

I think that I need firts to convert these numbers to dates, and then compare each one, to get the latest date, but I don't know how to do this.
I have to point that the list of numbers is dynamically created
I accept other suggestions, thank's.

Comment: are they *really* numbers or strings?

Comment: Latest day is 17 even if that is not contained in the list? Is it a `List<string>` or `List<int>`?

Comment: I create the list with strings

Comment: The latest date in the list

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `List<string>` with these dates in it as individual member, you can parse each string element to a date using pattern `yyyyMMdd` then order them in descending order and select the first one like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>
{
    "20151114",
    "20151115",
    "20151116",
};

var latestDate = list.Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .OrderByDescending(d => d)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give you back:

```
latestDate = {16/11/2015 12:00:00 AM}
```

Also to add, Since the format you have chosen to store string dates supports **natural sort order** you can also do:

```
var latestStringDate = list.OrderByDescending(r => r).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this will give you string date, not a `DateTime` object.

Comment: You don't know if `"2015112"` is possible, then you need `yyyyMMd` and the natural sort doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I can only guess that the format would remain same, otherwise one even has to specify multiple patterns in parsing as well.

Comment: `var latestStringDate = list.Max();` would be more efficient?

Comment: I convert the code to visual basic, but is not correct the sintaxis, I put this:                                                                                                     Dim list As New List(Of String)() From { _
 "20151114", _
 "20151115", _
 "20151116" _
}

             '  Dim latestDate = list.[Select](Function(d) DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).OrderByDescending(Function(d) d).FirstOrDefault()'

Answer (score 1):

it is more easy if you have "yyyyMMdd".
Convert in INT number and choose the more hight (bucle for), then convert to date only one number.
I think this way is more speedy.